# Exception in main thread No such element exception

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Java and I'm having some trouble figuring out where I'm going wrong with my program. I have it so it's doing a mad libs sort of thing where it reads a document with questions(or categories), then prompts for an answer on loop till it has all the answers. It commits these answers to a text file called "answers" then reads the file and prints a message, along with another file containing the full madlib.

I don't actually get an error upon compiling but after I've input all the answers I get

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: no line found

```
-at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540) 
-at reader.main(reader.java:68)
```

Here's the complete code for reference

```
import java.util.Scanner;                                        //     importing scanner object for usage
import java.io.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class reader{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException                   
    {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the name of a file");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);




    int limit = inputFile.nextInt();
    int n;
    inputFile.nextLine();
    PrintWriter answers = new PrintWriter("answers.txt");

    for(n = 0; n < limit; n++)
        {
        String line = inputFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
        answers.println(answer);
        }



    inputFile.close();
    answers.close();

    File useanswers = new File("answers.txt");
    Scanner inputFile2 = new Scanner(useanswers);
    String outputline = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline2 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline3 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline4 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline5 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline6 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline7 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline8 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline9 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline10 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline11 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline12 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline13 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline14 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline15 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline16 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline17 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline18 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    String outputline19 = inputFile2.nextLine();

    PrintWriter result = new PrintWriter("Madlibs_result.txt"); 
    System.out.println("Batman is " + outputline + ". Teenager " + outputline2 + 
     "was traumatized by " + outputline3 + "his parent's murder and vowed to " + outputline4 +
    " their deaths by bringing the " + outputline5 + " to justice. " + outputline6 + " used his " +
    outputline7 + "fortune to study criminology, to train his body to "  + outputline8 + " perfection, " +
    "and to acquire hight tech vehicles and "  + outputline9 + " to fight crime in his homw town of " + outputline10 + ". One night " + 
     outputline11 + "was " + outputline + " by a bat outside his window and decided to dress himself as a \"bat man\" to strike " +
      outputline12 + " in the \"" + outputline13 + " and "  + outputline14 + "\" hearts of "  + outputline15 + ". From that moment forward, " +
      outputline16 + " became \"Batman\" in his altered "  + outputline17);

    result.println("Batman is " + outputline + ". Teenager " + outputline2 + 
     "was traumatized by " + outputline3 + "his parent's murder and vowed to " + outputline4 +
    " their deaths by bringing the " + outputline5 + " to justice. " + outputline6 + " used his " +
    outputline7 + "fortune to study criminology, to train his body to "  + outputline8 + " perfection, " +
    "and to acquire hight tech vehicles and "  + outputline9 + " to fight crime in his homw town of " + outputline10 + ". One night " + 
     outputline11 + "was " + outputline + " by a bat outside his window and decided to dress himself as a \"bat man\" to strike " +
      outputline12 + " in the \"" + outputline13 + " and "  + outputline14 + "\" hearts of "  + outputline15 + ". From that moment forward, " +
      outputline16 + " became \"Batman\" in his altered "  + outputline17);


    result.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the file you are giving as input (answers.txt) ? it looks like it doesn't have the number of lines you expect in your code. Moreover which is line 68 in your code? Must be one of `inputFile2.nextLine();`

Comment: It is probably because of your inputFile.close() operation, can you try reusing a single scanner object?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, I had too many String outputline... lines, and I assume when it tried to go to the nonexistent 19th and 20th lines of the text file created, it gave me an error.